# Android : Where can I upload XML file

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm parsing XML file from HTTP Server to my android application, but I don't know, where I can upload an XML file in the server. Does anyone can help me out ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking , where can you get a sever so you can upload the xml file and have your app parse the file from there, you can get free shared servers if you google "[free shared hosting"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=3&gs_mss=free%20shared%20h&tok=NnjLQmMel0_CstNbx8_PsA&pq=free%20shared%20server&cp=15&gs_id=1w&xhr=t&q=free%20shared%20hosting&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=free%20shared%20hos&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ac9c1762bf41c86b&bpcl=35466521&ion=1&biw=1680&bih=925) .